# Getting sleep data from the Google fit API

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I've been trying for the last few days to get Sleep information from the google fit API.

I've managed to get data from the history API and the session API for the time period, but the activity list doesn't seem to include any sleep data.

I've been capturing the data in "Sleep as Android" and I've also tried "Instant". But don't see anything in the data sets coming back.

I seem to remember with the older fit app I'd see the sleep activity shown, but there's no sign of the data in the journal section of the new app.

Should I be able to get the data from the history or session data?

At the moment I'm using

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
   .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
   .read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
   .build();

Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context))
   .readData(readRequest)
   .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>(){
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
           List<DataSet> dataSets = dataReadResponse.getDataSets();
           for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                   for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()){
                      LogUtil.d("google fit Start: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " " + timeFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " End: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " " + timeFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " type: " + showDataType(dp.getValue(field)));
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing to get at the correct data. I see walking, still, running etc, but just no sleep!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send a session request that will read the `dataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT` or used the `Users.sessions` methods to correctly [record fitness data](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record) the sleep [activities](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types).

List of activities:

- Sleeping 72
- Light sleep  109
- Deep sleep   110
- REM sleep    111

Here is the [sample](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sleep-as-an-droid/20HYcUTAttY) code from Martin Stava that will show you on how to use Sleep as Anroid data from Google Fit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that session info already and I can see sessions that I start within fit itself, but I'm still not seeing anything from other apps (ie the ones that capture sleep data)

Comment: @Andrew facing same issue if you could guide something on it.